# Is it possible to know the location of an Anycast IP since they can be at multiple places at the same time?

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, ip, internet, cdn

With a Unicast IP we can know the geographical location of an IP address easily. But an Anycast IP address can be at multiple locations at the same time and depending on how close you are to the server you will be routed to the closest one.

So, if I'm connection over a CDN network, the IP address of `104.18.51.214` might take you to a server someone in USA or if you are connecting from Europe it may take you to a server somewhere in Europe. How can you then know where you have been routed geographically?

[image]

Comment: "_With a Unicast IP we can know the geographical location of an IP address easily._" Not really. If you try to geolocate, my IP address, it comes back over 1000 miles away. IP geolocation is not something to blindly trust, and different vendors will often have different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `traceroute` and check geo location of the last n IPs.

CHecking it manually should be easy or you can try to use script like https://github.com/benjojo/AnyCatch to detect which last IPs of `traceroute` is the first unicast IP and determine the geolocation from it.